# Formulation: "I like to see the beauty in ugly things"

Tags: phrase-requests

What would be a good way to express the following: "I like to see the beauty in ugly things"? (This is related to drawings, paintings and photography.)

Comment: Is it not a context where "searching for inner beauty" would fit?

Comment: I think that your phrase captures it quite well. Beauty and ugliness balanced against each other...is there a more subtle idea you're trying to convey?

Comment: I esteem to discern the pulchritude in repugnant entities.  Moar [smart words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/what-are-smart-words)!  (sorry...)

Comment: Though this is an old question, I think that it's off-topic as the OP is simply asking for a *more evocative* way to express something that he already knows how to say. This is perhaps marginally on-topic for writers.se, but not here.

Comment: @JSBᾶngs: English is not my mother tongue. Therefore I don't know how this subjective phrase appears to a native speaker. If english.stackexchange is not good for this, what is it good for then?

Comment: And another point: As you can see, I am not looking for synonyme sentences that sound better, I am looking for sentences that do express what I mean -- that's the reason why I haven't accepted any answer

Answer (score 2):

- I find beauty in the ugly.
- I find beauty in the mundane. (not the same as ugly)
- I see beauty in ugliness.
- To me, ugly is beautiful.
- Through my eyes, the ugly becomes beautiful.

Comment: This is a good answer because it shows that the original sentence can be interpreted in very different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I like to explore the beauty within the ugliness.

I like to capture the beauty within the ugliness.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to see the beauty in that which is grotesque